# Can anyone help me find what the output is?? this is in C++

Tags: c++, netbeans

Can anyone help me find what the output is?? this is in C++... homwork

A variable x globally defined in your program is assigned the integer value 3.  A variable x defined in a function named f_name is assigned the integer value 5.  Answer the following after looking at the code that follows.

```
1  #include <iostream>
2  using namespace std;
3  int f_name(int y);
4 
5  int x = 3;
6  
7  int main()
8  {
9   cout << x;
10  cout << f_name(x);
11  return 0;
12 }
13   
14 int f_name(int y)
15 {
16  int x = 5;
17  return (x + y);
18 }


  What is the output of line 9? _________ line 10? _______________
```

Comment: FYI: highlight your code in the editor and use the "code" button, that will keep your line breaks in place.

Comment: @newwie, why not execute your code and get the output yourself?

Comment: Is it homework? You should add a tag if it is.

Comment: @Mark B ya but its not giving me the right answers

Comment: @Peter where is the code button located?

Comment: @newwie the output it gives you when you run the program **is** the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

line 9 = 3
line 10 = 8 are the outputs.

At line 9, just printing the value of global variable **x**.
At line 10, just passing the value of `x` to f_name(iny y). Which means value of `y` at this function scope is **3**. Adding this to local variable `x` gives **8** which the function is returning.

---

I think, you are having trouble in understanding the scope of variables. To understand that, keeping this program in point of view, there are two kind of variables -

1. Local Variables
2. Global Variables

*Local variables* are variables that has local scope and are accessible only in the functions they are declared.

*Global variables* are variables whose life span starts at the begin of the program and ends only after program termination. Global variables at file scope are accessible any where with in the translation unit.

```
int main() 
{
  cout << x;   // x here is the global variable. Because, in main, there is no variable 
               // called x declared. So it prints 3
  cout << f_name(x); // Here you are passing the value of global variable x, which is 3
  return 0;
}

int f_name(int y) // The passed value ( i.e., 3 ) is copied to y. 
{
  int x = 5;
  return (x + y);  // Here you are not accessing global variable x. Because, there 
                   // is a local variable declared called x and initialize with value 5
                   // Now (5+3) = 8, which is returned.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

3 and 8. No?

In line 9 `cout << x;` prints the value of the global  `x` i.e 3.
In line 17

```
 return (x + y );  // outputs 8
```

x refers to local `x` whereas the value of y is equal to global `x`'s value since it is passed as an argument to the function.